# Aligning content in a custom tabular column environment to the top of each row

Tags: tables, alignment, columns

I have a customized tabular column style to fix the row heights in my table (which makes labels for poster boards at a conference, 4 labels per A4 page). It almost works, but the content is aligned with the *bottom* of the row and I want it aligned to the *top* of the row. What am I doing wrong? MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[sfdefault,black]{merriweather} %% Option 'black' gives heavier bold face
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
 >{\vbox to 6cm\bgroup\vspace{0pt}}%
 m{#1}%
 <{\egroup}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|C{10cm} | C{10cm}|}
\hline
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P128}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Plant Psychology: an integrated approach utilising Neural Networks}
\end{center}
&
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P134}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Placeholder Text: Nothing to see here}
\end{center}\tabularnewline

\hline

\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P135}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title}
\end{center}
&
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P428}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Fantastic Bees and Where to Find Them}
\end{center}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Separate question: how can I add padding around each border to space out the labels for cutting up?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `\vfil`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[sfdefault,black]{merriweather} %% Option 'black' gives heavier bold face
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
 >{\vbox to 6cm\bgroup\vspace{0pt}}%
  m{#1}
 <{\vfil\egroup}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|C{10cm} | C{10cm}|}
\hline
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P128}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Plant Psychology: an integrated approach utilising Neural Networks}
\end{center}
&
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P134}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Placeholder Text: Nothing to see here}
\end{center}\tabularnewline

\hline

\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P135}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title}
\end{center}
&
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P428}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Fantastic Bees and Where to Find Them}
\end{center}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want more padding, you can raise the value of `\tabcolsep` (the default value is 5 pt) and put \vspace{10pt}`instead of`\vspace{0pt}`in your`\newcolumntype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[sfdefault,black]{merriweather} %% Option 'black' gives heavier bold face
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
 >{\vbox to 6cm\bgroup\vspace{10pt}}%
  m{#1}
 <{\vfil\egroup}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|C{10cm} | C{10cm}|}
\hline
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P128}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Plant Psychology: an integrated approach utilising Neural Networks}
\end{center}
&
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P134}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Placeholder Text: Nothing to see here}
\end{center}\tabularnewline

\hline

\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P135}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title A Much Longer Poster Title}
\end{center}
&
\begin{center}
\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont{}\textsf{\textbf{P428}}\par
%\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont{}\emph{Fantastic Bees and Where to Find Them}
\end{center}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]